# Modify Django settings variables in a middleware

Tags: python, django, settings, middleware

I set a variable MAX_REQUEST = 100 in settings.py

I write a middleware which may lower this value for request origining from a proxy ip address by the following code:

```
settings.MAX_REQUEST = 10
```

However, looks like the above modification affects all legitimate users.

Is it normal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. `settings` is a module referenced all over by Django (and probably your code too). Modifying any variable in `settings` is like modifying a global variable and alters the behaviour of your whole web app.

Answer (score 0):

Django settings are global. They affect the whole process.

Answer (score 0):

If you want 'per user' variables, I suggest you look at [How to use sessions](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/).